# benson formula and lattice sum

Tags: calculus

I read in the paper about the lattice sum the folowing sum
it seem get it about the mellin transform
$$\sum _{\text{k2}=1}^{\infty } \sum _{\text{k1}=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{((\text{k1}+2)+(\text{k2}+4))^s}=\zeta (s-1)-8 \zeta (s)+3\ 2^{1-s}+4^{1-s}+2^{1-s} 3^{-s}+5\ 3^{-s}+3\ 5^{-s}+7^{-s}+7$$
but i do not how to get ? numerically it seem works.
sorry the exact anwer is $$2^{-2 s} 15^{-s} \left(2^{2 s} 15^s \zeta (s-1)-7\ 2^{2 s} 15^s \zeta (s)+2^{2 s+1} 3^s+2^{2 s+1} 3^{s+1} 5^s+3^{s+1} 5^s+2^{2 s+2} 5^s+5^{s+1} 6^s+10^s\right)$$

Comment: **Hint:** In how many ways can you write $n=k_1+k_2$ as a sum of two positive terms ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\quad\displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac1{(m+n)^a}~=~\zeta(a-1).\quad$ Can you take it from here ? :-$)$

Comment: Hi Lucian i do not understood want you want to mean??.

Comment: @antonioasis: You honestly don't see any $($obvious$)$ connection between this series, and the one from the actual question ?